# Adding fields Dynamically in MongoDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB.
  My application is dynamic form builder that lets users add dynamic fields on the form. None of the field on the form is fix or static.  The user can add any number and any type of fields such as Textbox, Textarea, Dropdown, Checkbox, Radiobutton etc fields on the form and save the form.
 Can Mongo DB be used for such storage and fetching the data ? 
 How the data to be stored in Mongo DB and fetched to display the form?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC as a frontend
MongoDB as a backend

Hope for the best answer :)

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, you don't have a predefined schema for your collection, if you decide that only that document will have an `name` field, you can. The schema is dynamic so you can add any data you want in your case. It's really useful but you have to be careful after when you query your database for `undefined` value. Hope this will help you.